# Make a post redirect url in php

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I am using a search function in my wordpress site which is working fine. I want to generate a url which I can type in the browser and it gives me results. Like a bookmark url. Right now i am not getting any url with search queries in it like soething

`http://www.example.com/posts/?venues=london`

I want something like the above url. My form code is

```
<form name="search-fomr" action="<?php echo site_url().'/seminars-list';?>" method="post">
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: `<form name="search-fomr" action="<?php echo site_url().'/posts/?venues=-seminars-list';?>" method="post">`

Comment: I am passing the search parameters into the function from a drop down list. I just wana include the query in the url so I can use it directly.

Comment: `<form name="search-fomr" action="<?php echo site_url().'/posts/' ;?>" method="GET">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the post type post to get. Try this and set input name = venues

```
<form name="search-fomr" action="www.example.com/posts/" method="get">
```

Comment: I figured it out ... Thanks for push